# C extension for 'Murmur3Partitioner' was not compiled

Tags: python, cassandra

I'm working on this [python-cassandra tutorial](http://planetcassandra.org/getting-started-with-apache-cassandra-and-python-part-ii/).

When I'm running this command

```
cluster = Cluster(
  contact_points=['127.0.0.1'],
  load_balancing_policy= 
     TokenAwarePolicy(DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy(local_dc='datacenter1')),
  default_retry_policy = RetryPolicy()
 )
session = cluster.connect('demo')
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
>>> session = cluster.connect('mykeyspace')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", 
          line 700, in connect
    self.load_balancing_policy.check_supported()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cassandra/policies.py", 
          line 345, in check_supported
          (self.__class__.__name__, self._cluster_metadata.partitioner))
    Exception: TokenAwarePolicy cannot be used with the cluster partitioner
    (org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner) because the relevant C extension 
    for this driver was not compiled. See the installation instructions for details 
    on building and installing the C extensions.
```

However, when I run the below command that's supposed to rebuild the C extensions as it said in the document, I'm getting the confirmation that everything is right.

```
user1@mybox-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt-get install gcc python-dev
[sudo] password for user1: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gcc is already the newest version.
python-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 254 not upgraded.
```

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you've installed gcc and python-dev, you need to go back and reinstall the Cassandra Python driver. Here's what the whole sequence would look like, assuming you also install the support for compiling libev:

```
$ sudo apt-get install gcc python-dev
$ sudo apt-get install libev4 libev-dev
$ sudo pip uninstall cassandra-driver
$ sudo pip install cassandra-driver
```

On the 2nd install, the C extensions should compile correctly.